# Show Google Map View Tab - Delay in Loading Markers from Geocoding?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, geocoding

I have a tab in my tab based app which shows Google Maps. It loads a number of markers for about 60 places using geo-coding via a JSON based method.

The problem is that when you click on the tab the view doesn't change until all the places have been loaded. Is there anyway I can show the map view instantly and then let the app update all the places ?

I have pasted the way I am creating the markers below :

```
while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

    Address = mCursor.getString(4);
    Name = mCursor.getString(0);


    String noSpaces = Address.replaceAll(" ", "+");

    JSONObject geocoded = getLocationInfo(noSpaces);
    GeoPoint point = getGeoPoint(geocoded);


    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
    CustomizedItemOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
    new CustomizedItemOverlay(drawable, this);

    OverlayItem overlayitem = 
    new OverlayItem(point, Name, Address);

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and inside doInBackground make search and inside onPostExecute that will get result from doInBackground make overlays insertion process.